# jQuery hide and show panel

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the following code, I am trying to build two panels; new order panel and track order panel. The problem that I am facing is the components of both panels open in the first panel. 
I am not sure if you understnad the problem. This is code and you can try to understand it clearly:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscss/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip1").click(function(){
    $(".panel1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
div.panel,p.flip
{
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.panel
{
height:220px;
display:none;
}
div.panel1,p.flip1
{
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.panel1
{
height:220px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="panel">
<form action="Order.php" method="post">
   Name<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="name" size="60" type="text"                 AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF><br /><br />

   Subject<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="subject" size="60" type="text"     id="subject"><br /> <br />

   Email<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="email" size="60" type="text"><br /> <br />

   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
</div>


<div class="panel1">
<form action="Track.php" method="post">
   ID<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="id" size="60" type="text"         AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF><br /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
</div>

<p class="flip">New Order</p>
<br/><br/><br/>
<p class="flip1">Track Order</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: it's often of much help to post something on jsfiddle about an issue with html/js/css here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/Yu7Gh/

Comment: Btw, you don't have to use `$(document).ready()` for each of those functions -- use one to wrap all, or none and put the JS code at the bottom of the page, or use none and use `.live()` for binding events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the wrong order of your html code, try this:

```
<body>

  <div class="panel">
    <form action="Order.php" method="post">
      Name<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="name" size="60" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF><br /><br />

      Subject<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="subject" size="60" type="text" id="subject"><br /> <br />

      Email<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="email" size="60" type="text"><br /> <br />

      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <p class="flip">New Order</p>
  <br/><br/><br/>

  <div class="panel1">
    <form action="Track.php" method="post">
      ID<br /><input style="font-weight: bold;" name="id" size="60" type="text"         AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <p class="flip1">Track Order</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you just put them in the wrong order. Use `panel`, then `flip`, then `panel1`, then `flip1`.

Answer (score 1):

I made changes for you. Yes, you made mistakes on the order of the HTML structure. You can check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/zhujy_8833/pAerK/

Basically, please make the order like this:

1. div.panel
2. p.flip
3. div.panel1
4. p.flip1

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

In markup your order is panel, panel1, New Order header, and Track Order header.  This is the order in which they will display.